# Function going up and down in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a function going up and down, here is what I have, perhaps it is more explicit about what I want:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,5) -- (0,0) -- (10,0);
  \foreach \n in {1,...,20}
  {
   \node (a\n) at ({10-(10/\n)},0) {};
   \node (b\n) at ({10-((10*\n + 5)/(\n*\n + \n))},5) {};
   \draw (a\n) -- (b\n);
  }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And the output:
[image]

But I'm having problems connecting top points with bottom points, in the code I want a line from b\n to a\n+1. I have tried using `evaluate` as follows:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,5) -- (0,0) -- (10,0);
  \foreach \n [evaluate=\n as \m using {int(\n+1)}] in {1,...,20}
  {
   \node (a\n) at ({10-(10/\n)},0) {};
   \node (b\n) at ({10-((10*\n + 5)/(\n*\n + \n))},5) {};
   \draw (a\n) -- (b\n);
   \draw (b\n) -- (a\m); %this is not working
  }
  \end{tikzpicture}
```

And `\pgfmathtruncatemacro` adding something that I believe can stop trying to draw a line from b20 to a21 (a node that doesn't exist):

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,5) -- (0,0) -- (10,0);
\foreach \n in {1,...,20}
{
 \pgfmathtruncatemacro{\m}{\n + 1};
 \node (a\n) at ({10-(10/\n)},0) {};
 \node (b\n) at ({10-((10*\n + 5)/(\n*\n + \n))},5) {};
 \draw (a\n) -- (b\n);
 \draw (b\n) -- (a\m); %this is not working
 \ifnum \m<20
  \breakforeach
\fi
}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

But in any case the compiler says: `! Package pgf Error: No shape named a2 is known`. So any help to solve my problem will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this? (Note that I replace `minimal` by standalone and `node` by `coordinate` to avoid gaps.)

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw (0,5) -- (0,0) -- (10,0);
  \foreach \n in {1,...,20}
  {
   \coordinate (a\n) at ({10-(10/\n)},0) {};
   \coordinate (b\n) at ({10-((10*\n + 5)/(\n*\n + \n))},5) {};
   \draw \ifnum\n>1  (b\the\numexpr\n-1) -- \fi (a\n) -- (b\n);

  }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]